# How do I append a graph to last column of a table?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

```
rmsdata= Partition[ReadList["RMStabledata.txt", Number],29]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2.96142, 36.7357, 9.05539, 9, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1, 1, -2, 2, -4,
>  2, -3, 1, -5, 1, -7, 1, -6, 0, -7, -1, -9, -1}, {1, 2.68942, 
> 30.2974, 8.24621, 8, 0, 0, -2, 0, -4, 0, -5, 1, -7, 1, -6, 2, -8, 
> 2, -9, 1, -10, 0, -8, 0, -7, -1, -8, -2}, {2, 3.04704, 38.8905, 10.,
> 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, -2, 2, -4, 2, -3, 3, -2, 4, -3, 5, -5, 5, -6,
> 6, -7, 7, -6, 8}, {3, 2.0943, 18.3723, 4.24264, 14, 0, 0, 1, -1, 
> 0, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -2, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1, 3, -2, 4, -3, 
> 3}, {4, 2.97999, 37.1979, 10., 9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 
> 2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 7, 5, 8, 6}, {5, 2.48083, 25.7801, 
> 7.61577, 7, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6,
> 4, 5, 3, 7, 3}}
> ```

```
sortedrmsdata = SortBy[rmsdata, #[[5]] &]  

xydata = Partition[Flatten[Take[sortedrmsdata, All, {6, 29}]], 2]  

gridedvalues = Take[sortedrmsdata, All, {1, 5}]  

col = {SpanFromBelow, SpanFromBelow, SpanFromBelow, SpanFromBelow, 
   SpanFromBelow, SpanFromBelow};  

Table[AppendTo[gridedvalues[[i]], col[[i]]], {i, 6}]  grided = Prepend[
  gridedvalues, {"Number", "RMS displacement", "Volume", 
   "RMS end-end", "Interactions", "Graph"}]  

Grid[AppendTo[
  grided, {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove,
    SpanFromAbove, 
   ListPlot[Partition[xydata, 12], Mesh -> All, 
    MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], Joined -> True, 
    PlotLegend -> Take[sortedrmsdata, All, 1]]}], Frame -> All]
```

Worked:

```
col ={ListPlot[Partition[xydata, 12], Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], Joined -> True], SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove};
gridedvalues = Take[sortedrmsdata, All, {1, 5}];Table[AppendTo[gridedvalues[[i]], col[[i]]], {i, 6}];
grided = Prepend[gridedvalues, {"Number", "RMS displacement", "Volume", "RMS end-end", "Interactions", "Graph"}];
Grid[grided, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Right now this outputs a grid with 6 columns but instead of the graph being positioned in the entire last column it is in the bottom corner.

Comment: I want the graph to be the last column where it reads Graph not the row. I tried posting a picture but I dont have enough reputation.Thank you

Comment: Also, I only have 6 columns the last one that you show isnt showing on mine

Comment: u have 7 columns and rmsdata=data i believe

Comment: @nasser you have to have 10 rep or more befire you can pist images.

Comment: The data above is supposed to be rmsdata. I think I fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the complete solution,but I may be this way you can do it.

```
gridedvalues = Take[sortedrmsdata, All, {1, 6}];    (*not 5*)
```

I don't know what this `SpanFromBelow` means because it doesn't show up in documentation.But I have let it be there.

```
Table[AppendTo[gridedvalues[[i]], col[[i]]], {i, 6}]; 
grided = Prepend[
  gridedvalues, {"Number", "RMS displacement", "Volume", 
   "RMS end-end", "Interactions", "Graph"}]
```

Instead of adding it at end, append plot here, as under

```
AppendTo[gridedvalues, 
  ListPlot[Partition[xydata, 12], Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]];
Grid[AppendTo[grided, gridedvalues], Alignment -> Right, Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Not sure why but this didnt quite work for me but led me in the right direction. I edited my question with what worked for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am glad, I could help :)